# How to transpose table in presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a question, which results in

```
A  |  B | C | D | E
2. |  3 | 10| 25| 60
```

How to convert it to

```
Reason | Percentage
A.     | 2
B.     | 3
C.     | 10
D.     | 25
E.     | 60
```

(ignore the pots)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [UNNEST](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) function.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM T
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY[
 ROW('A', A), 
 ROW('B', B), 
 ROW('C', C), 
 ROW('D', D),
 ROW('E', E)
]) AS v(Reason, Percentage);
```

another way is using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 'A' Reason , A Percentage FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' Reason , B Percentage FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' Reason , C Percentage FROM T
//....
```

Comment: AFAIK `unnest` supports multiple arrays so you can do `unnest(array['A', 'B', ...], array[A, B, ...])`.